# How to prepare sumologic for nodes

Tags: javascript, node.js, sumologic

I am trying to implement sumologic for my node js application by using [this NPM Package](http://www.npmjs.com/package/winston-sumologic-transport).

Here is what I am trying by example but I am not getting any error and my log is also not getting placed in sumologic.

`npm i winston-sumologic-transport`

In my index.js

```
var winston = require('winston');
var { SumoLogic } = require('winston-sumologic-transport');


app.listen(port, () => {
  var options = {
    url: process.env.SUMO_LOGIC_URL
  }
    var meta = {
    winston.add(SumoLogic, options);
    winston.info("Hello  mssage");
   console.log(`Server running on ${port}...`);
});
```

I am not getting any idea either how to support sumologic in node js app.